# Variable sheet names in a sumifs formula excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

Have the following working formula

```
=SUMIFS('1'!$U$2:$U$32,'1'!$Z$2:$Z$32,{1007,1008},'1'!$AB$2:$AB$32,"*"&March!B5&"")
```

And I'm trying to replace the 3 hard coded references to sheet 1 with a variable located in C3. My attempt was as follows using indirect *(I've used this before on single conditional statements but not on multiple conditionals)*:

```
=SUMIFS(INDIRECT("'"&$C3&"'!$U$2:$U$32),INDIRECT("'"&$C3&"'!$Z$2:$Z$32),{1007,1008},INDIRECT("'"&$C3&"'!$AB$2:$AB$32),"*"&March!B5&"")
```

This however comes up with errors.

Appreciate some help in pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: does CSE fix it?

Comment: @Jeeped not it doesn't.

Comment: Try wrapping in SUM() and CSE.

Comment: @ScottCraner no go, points to the 2nd Indirect but no information on what might be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't closed the strings in your indirect functions:

```
=SUMIFS(INDIRECT("'"&$C3&"'!$U$2:$U$32"),INDIRECT("'"&$C3&"'!$Z$2:$Z$32"),{1007,1008},INDIRECT("'"&$C3&"'!$AB$2:$AB$32"),"*"&March!B5&"")
```

Comment: Thanks @Michael, still getting my head around the use of indirects

Comment: Good catch! Missed that myself.